# "at event" vs. "on event"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is a better preposition for the word "*event*"?

- at
- on

Specifically I want to say:

- Lector at an event
- Lector on an event

Which is the correct one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Lector' is an unusual word in modern English. I assume you mean 'read' as one might read a lesson at a church service.

Did you perhaps mean 'lecture'?

If I say 'lecture at an event', that means to give a talk to a gathering of people at an event.

If I say 'lecture on an event', that means to give a formal talk about what happened at a particular event, at some other time and place.

Does that help?

Comment: The usual usage of "on event" is synonymous to "in case of event", common in IT - an event happens, like mouse click, and an operation is performed 'on event', meaning when mouse is clicked. "At event" is almost strictly reserved to "event" meaning something like a meeting, concert, conference or such. While two trains colliding is an event for sure, you wouldn't say you met someone *at* such an event...

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helps. I meant lector in terms of a speaker.

Comment: 'Lector' though it exists, is a term that is hardly ever used nowadays. In fact I had to look it up in Oxford Dictionaries, which give its meaning as 'reader, especially someone who reads lessons in a church service'. Another meaning is 'lecturer, especially one employed in a foreign university to teach in their native language'. But you may get some puzzled looks if you use 'lector' rather than 'lecturer' in an English-speaking country.