# Which is correct: debut 'in' or 'at'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

Which is correct:

1) Your debut **in** the World Junior Figure Skating Championship.

Or

2) Your debut **at** the World Junior Figure Skating Championship.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156548/at-event-vs-on-event

Answer (score 1):

'Debut' as either noun or verb could happily take many prepositions, including both 'in' and 'at'. Which depends on context.

For a skater, either would work equally well.

For someone not competing, perhaps the host or master of ceremonies, interval entertainers, stewards or doormen 'in' would imply too close a relationship so 'at' would be much more appropriate.

A big cruise ship as venue for the championships would open up the possibility of 'aboard' or 'on' or many another.

Comment: Ah… but today it seems more obvious a "debut" is generally "at" a place, as Thisthat Opera House or "in" a medium, as opera or (slightly, perhaps, but still) stretching the point.

To me, the example seems unfortunate: the venue fits a place and skating a medium; championships, neither.

Call me archaic; I think “debut” with “championships” stretches the meaning too far… as when a local newspaper calls a big celebrity’s appearance at a local venue some kind of “debut.”

If you must use “debut” please don’t worry about “at” or “in”.